# After making a query Chinese characters show up in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am stuck with a problem in my database. I have a table with statistical data, there are numbers and descriptions of the product. When I run a query to add this data to our summary table, in the description of the products it shows some symbols and Chinese characters.

I would really appreciate your answers, but I am not a programmer or a pro in SQL, so if you could use some easy language for me, I would be really happy.
Thanks

I deleted the dataset, made it like a text (without formulas inside), checked the language of the database, and rewrote some positions manually, but still it shows these characters.
I have seen a related question, but it was regarding programming queries using R language, which I have zero knowledge in.